# Google Drive - Automatically create file weekly

Tags: automation, google-drive-api

I have a template presentation file in google drive "Weekly presentation".
Every friday, I would like to create **automatically** a copy of this template adding the date to the name ex: "01-01-2024 - Weekly presentation"

Is this possible?

If this is not the right place to ask this question, please guide me to the appropriate space

Comment: As a simple method, how about using Google Apps Script with the time-driven trigger? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) I think that when the time-driven trigger for Google Apps Script is used, your goal can be achieved by executing the script without login to Google. But, in your question, there is not tags related to the languages. So, if this was not included in your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: This worked for me, add it as answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `This worked for me, add it as answer and I'll accept it`, I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tanaike's comment I managed to do it

The process is the following:

- create an apps Script that creates a copy:
- Create a trigger that runs every period of time and triggers the following function

  function duplicateMyFile() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("<YOUR_FILE_ID>");
  // Create new file
  file.makeCopy("New File Name");
  }

P-S: I can't seem to format the code correctly, feel free to edit if you can solve this

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know how to create a singular file through API (let's say you have a basic Python script), then you can execute it via a bash script using [cron](https://crontab.guru/) (click to understand how to set time intervals easily) for it to execute every Friday.